# Sorting prime numbers on two sets of equals weights

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic

Lets denote $(p_n)$ the sequence of all prime numbers $(p_1=2, p_2=3,\ldots)$.

The conjecture is the following.

> For $n$ odd and greater than $2$,
>
> $$\exists I \subset \{1,\ldots ,n\} \quad \sum_{i\in I } p_i=\sum_{i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\setminus I} p_i.$$

For instance, $n=3$ works because $2+3=5$ $(I=\{1,2\})$.

But also $n=5$ because $2+5+7=3+11$ $(I=\{1,2\})$.

And also $n=7$ because $2+3+7+17=5+11+13$ $(I=\{1,2\})$.

We can prove that it can't work for $n$ even by parity (we would have an odd number of odd prime numbers).

We can reformulate the problem like this:

> For $n$ odd and greater than $2$,
>
> $$\exists I \subset \{1,\ldots ,n\} \quad \sum_{i\in I } p_i=\frac 12\sum_{i\leqslant n} p_i.$$

I honestly don't know how to start here, and I don't even know if this could be true. Do you have any leads ?

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this problem here before, with the addition that for $n$ even you can get the two sums to differ by 1. But how to search for it?

Comment: I found a solution on MathOverflow, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34581/a-prime-sequence-can-be-partitioned-into-two-sets-of-equal-or-consecutive-sum